# Deleting keyboard shortcuts in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I need to delete or change at least a shortcut on Windows 8, <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> for instance.

When I press this combination, I get "Share" charm or whatever this thing is called.

This is useless. I need this combination (and many other key combos) do particular things like typing a command in PuTTY window.

I used AutoHotkey on Windows 7 and it worked great, except on Windows 8 AHK does not seem to override built-in keyboard shortcuts. I can only use <kbd>Win</kbd>+*some key* combination that happens to be free.

So how do I delete this <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> shortcut?

Another answer on superuser suggested this: http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/ but this seems to remap entire keys, while I need to delete <kbd>Win</kbd>-*something* shortcut.

Comment: You can't delete a Windows 8 Shortcut key, you can't even change it.

Comment: Apparently it's possible, I just worked out how to do it, see answer.

Comment: @Ramhound: Of course, one small thing worth pointing out is that the registry edit will disable *all* Win-key shortcuts. There's no way to selectively disable just a few of them without third party software.

Comment: @Karan - I didn't fully read the discloser statement....oops

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out you CAN override built-in Windows Winkey-something shortcuts by using the current version of [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/):

```
#h::
Send something{ENTER}
sleep 300
return
```

I used older install before apparently, after reinstalling using latest AHK version and rebooting Win-H works when configured in AHK (deleting it from script and reloading script in AHK restores original shortcut, like "Share" for Win-H).

Comment: yes with additional software it is possible to overite the existing hotkeys in Windows 8, but in my answer above i meant that you can't do it just with Windows 8 settings without additional 3rd party software.